# Use SVG over and over again in my ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am still a begginer, I know my code are bad. What I want to achieve is to reuse the svg in the fifth page with a className "emoji" its has a comment {/* ------- SQD0 --------- */} and it will have 10 of these (SDQ10) is there a way to just use this svg to other SQD's?

```js
import React from "react";
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { multiStepContext } from "../StepContext";
import "../PageCSS/Fifth.scss";
import notApplicableGrey from "../img/na-grey-img.png";
import notApplicableRed from "../img/na-img.png";

export default function Fifth({ handleCloseModal }) {
  const { setStep, userData, setUserData } = React.useContext(multiStepContext);
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = React.useState(notApplicableGrey);

  const ratingTextMap = {
    1: "Strongly Disagree",
    2: "Disagree",
    3: "Neither Agree nor Disagree",
    4: "Agree",
    5: "Strongly Agree",
    6: "Not Applicable",
  };

  const [sqd0, setsqd0Rating] = React.useState(null);

  const handleIconRed = (event) => {
    setImageSrc(notApplicableRed);
  };
  const handleIconGrey = (event) => {
    setImageSrc(notApplicableGrey);
  };

  // ---------- HANDLE RATING CHANGE -------------- //
  const sqd0handleRatingChange = (event) => {
    const rating = event.target.value;
    console.log("SQD0 rating:", rating);
    setsqd0Rating(rating);
  };

  // ---------- HANDLE DISABLE -------------- //
  const sqd0handleDisable = (x, sqdClass) => {
    const rating = x;
    console.log(rating);
    setsqd0Rating(rating);
    disableCheckedRadioInputs(sqdClass);
  };
  // ---------- DISABLE ALL INPUT RADIO CHECKED -------------- //
  const disableCheckedRadioInputs = (sqdClass) => {
    const sqdElements = document.querySelectorAll("." + sqdClass);

    sqdElements.forEach((element) => {
      const radioInputs = element.querySelectorAll(
        'input[type="radio"]:checked'
      );

      radioInputs.forEach((input) => {
        input.checked = false;
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="page-container">
      {/* ------- SQD0 --------- */}
      <div className={`feedback sqd0`}>
        <label>
          <b>
            <i>SQD0. </i>
          </b>
          I am satisfied with the service that I availed.
        </label>
        <div className="rating">
          {[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1].map((rating) => (
            <React.Fragment key={rating}>
              {rating !== 6 ? (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="rating_0"
                    id={`sqd0Rating-${rating}`}
                    value={rating}
                    onChange={sqd0handleRatingChange}
                    onClick={handleIconGrey}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor={`sqd0Rating-${rating}`}></label>
                </React.Fragment>
              ) : (
                <React.Fragment>
                  {/* Add the image or icon for the "not applicable" rating */}
                  <img
                    id={`sqd0Rating-6`}
                    className="rating ratingImage"
                    src={imageSrc}
                    alt="Not Applicable"
                    style={{ height: "23px", width: "23px", cursor: "pointer" }}
                    onClick={() => {
                      sqd0handleDisable(6, "sqd0");
                      handleIconRed();
                    }}
                  />
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
          <div className="emoji-wrapper">
            <div className="emoji">
              <svg
                className="sqd0Rating-0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b" />
                <path
                  d="M512 256c0 141.44-114.64 256-256 256-80.48 0-152.32-37.12-199.28-95.28 43.92 35.52 99.84 56.72 160.72 56.72 141.36 0 256-114.56 256-256 0-60.88-21.2-116.8-56.72-160.72C474.8 103.68 512 175.52 512 256z"
                  fill="#f4c534"
                />
                <ellipse
                  transform="scale(-1) rotate(31.21 715.433 -595.455)"
                  cx="166.318"
                  cy="199.829"
                  rx="56.146"
                  ry="56.13"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <ellipse
                  transform="rotate(-148.804 180.87 175.82)"
                  cx="180.871"
                  cy="175.822"
                  rx="28.048"
                  ry="28.08"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <ellipse
                  transform="rotate(-113.778 194.434 165.995)"
                  cx="194.433"
                  cy="165.993"
                  rx="8.016"
                  ry="5.296"
                  fill="#5a5f63"
                />
                <ellipse
                  transform="scale(-1) rotate(31.21 715.397 -1237.664)"
                  cx="345.695"
                  cy="199.819"
                  rx="56.146"
                  ry="56.13"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <ellipse
                  transform="rotate(-148.804 360.25 175.837)"
                  cx="360.252"
                  cy="175.84"
                  rx="28.048"
                  ry="28.08"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <ellipse
                  transform="scale(-1) rotate(66.227 254.508 -573.138)"
                  cx="373.794"
                  cy="165.987"
                  rx="8.016"
                  ry="5.296"
                  fill="#5a5f63"
                />
                <path
                  d="M370.56 344.4c0 7.696-6.224 13.92-13.92 13.92H155.36c-7.616 0-13.92-6.224-13.92-13.92s6.304-13.92 13.92-13.92h201.296c7.696.016 13.904 6.224 13.904 13.92z"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                className="sqd0Rating-1"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b" />
                <path
                  d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.7 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58.1 47 95.3 118.8 95.3 199.3z"
                  fill="#f4c534"
                />
                <path
                  d="M328.4 428a92.8 92.8 0 0 0-145-.1 6.8 6.8 0 0 1-12-5.8 86.6 86.6 0 0 1 84.5-69 86.6 86.6 0 0 1 84.7 69.8c1.3 6.9-7.7 10.6-12.2 5.1z"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <path
                  d="M269.2 222.3c5.3 62.8 52 113.9 104.8 113.9 52.3 0 90.8-51.1 85.6-113.9-2-25-10.8-47.9-23.7-66.7-4.1-6.1-12.2-8-18.5-4.2a111.8 111.8 0 0 1-60.1 16.2c-22.8 0-42.1-5.6-57.8-14.8-6.8-4-15.4-1.5-18.9 5.4-9 18.2-13.2 40.3-11.4 64.1z"
                  fill="#f4c534"
                />
                <path
                  d="M357 189.5c25.8 0 47-7.1 63.7-18.7 10 14.6 17 32.1 18.7 51.6 4 49.6-26.1 89.7-67.5 89.7-41.6 0-78.4-40.1-82.5-89.7A95 95 0 0 1 298 174c16 9.7 35.6 15.5 59 15.5z"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <path
                  d="M396.2 246.1a38.5 38.5 0 0 1-38.7 38.6 38.5 38.5 0 0 1-38.6-38.6 38.6 38.6 0 1 1 77.3 0z"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <path
                  d="M380.4 241.1c-3.2 3.2-9.9 1.7-14.9-3.2-4.8-4.8-6.2-11.5-3-14.7 3.3-3.4 10-2 14.9 2.9 4.9 5 6.4 11.7 3 15z"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <path
                  d="M242.8 222.3c-5.3 62.8-52 113.9-104.8 113.9-52.3 0-90.8-51.1-85.6-113.9 2-25 10.8-47.9 23.7-66.7 4.1-6.1 12.2-8 18.5-4.2 16.2 10.1 36.2 16.2 60.1 16.2 22.8 0 42.1-5.6 57.8-14.8 6.8-4 15.4-1.5 18.9 5.4 9 18.2 13.2 40.3 11.4 64.1z"
                  fill="#f4c534"
                />
                <path
                  d="M155 189.5c-25.8 0-47-7.1-63.7-18.7-10 14.6-17 32.1-18.7 51.6-4 49.6 26.1 89.7 67.5 89.7 41.6 0 78.4-40.1 82.5-89.7A95 95 0 0 0 214 174c-16 9.7-35.6 15.5-59 15.5z"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <path
                  d="M115.8 246.1a38.5 38.5 0 0 0 38.7 38.6 38.5 38.5 0 0 0 38.6-38.6 38.6 38.6 0 1 0-77.3 0z"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <path
                  d="M131.6 241.1c3.2 3.2 9.9 1.7 14.9-3.2 4.8-4.8 6.2-11.5 3-14.7-3.3-3.4-10-2-14.9 2.9-4.9 5-6.4 11.7-3 15z"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                className="sqd0Rating-2"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b" />
                <path
                  d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.7 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58.1 47 95.3 118.8 95.3 199.3z"
                  fill="#f4c534"
                />
                <path
                  d="M336.6 403.2c-6.5 8-16 10-25.5 5.2a117.6 117.6 0 0 0-110.2 0c-9.4 4.9-19 3.3-25.6-4.6-6.5-7.7-4.7-21.1 8.4-28 45.1-24 99.5-24 144.6 0 13 7 14.8 19.7 8.3 27.4z"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <path
                  d="M276.6 244.3a79.3 79.3 0 1 1 158.8 0 79.5 79.5 0 1 1-158.8 0z"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <circle cx="340" cy="260.4" r="36.2" fill="#3e4347" />
                <g fill="#fff">
                  <ellipse
                    transform="rotate(-135 326.4 246.6)"
                    cx="326.4"
                    cy="246.6"
                    rx="6.5"
                    ry="10"
                  />
                  <path d="M231.9 244.3a79.3 79.3 0 1 0-158.8 0 79.5 79.5 0 1 0 158.8 0z" />
                </g>
                <circle cx="168.5" cy="260.4" r="36.2" fill="#3e4347" />
                <ellipse
                  transform="rotate(-135 182.1 246.7)"
                  cx="182.1"
                  cy="246.7"
                  rx="10"
                  ry="6.5"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                className="sqd0Rating-3"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b" />
                <path
                  d="M370.56 384.4c0 7.696-6.224 13.92-13.92 13.92H155.36c-7.616 0-13.92-6.224-13.92-13.92s6.304-13.92 13.92-13.92h201.296c7.696.016 13.904 6.224 13.904 13.92z"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />

                <path
                  d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.7 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58.1 47 95.3 118.8 95.3 199.3z"
                  fill="#f4c534"
                />
                <g fill="#fff">
                  <ellipse cx="356.4" cy="205.3" rx="81.1" ry="81" />
                </g>
                <ellipse
                  cx="356.4"
                  cy="205.3"
                  rx="44.2"
                  ry="44.2"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <g fill="#fff">
                  <ellipse
                    transform="scale(-1) rotate(45 454 -906)"
                    cx="375.3"
                    cy="188.1"
                    rx="12"
                    ry="8.1"
                  />
                  <ellipse cx="155.6" cy="205.3" rx="81.1" ry="81" />
                </g>
                <ellipse
                  cx="155.6"
                  cy="205.3"
                  rx="44.2"
                  ry="44.2"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <ellipse
                  transform="scale(-1) rotate(45 454 -421.3)"
                  cx="174.5"
                  cy="188"
                  rx="12"
                  ry="8.1"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
              </svg>

              <svg
                className="sqd0Rating-4"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" fill="#ffd93b" />
                <path
                  d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.7 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58.1 47 95.3 118.8 95.3 199.3z"
                  fill="#f4c534"
                />
                <path
                  d="M232.3 201.3c0 49.2-74.3 94.2-74.3 94.2s-74.4-45-74.4-94.2a38 38 0 0 1 74.4-11.1 38 38 0 0 1 74.3 11.1z"
                  fill="#e24b4b"
                />
                <path
                  d="M96.1 173.3a37.7 37.7 0 0 0-12.4 28c0 49.2 74.3 94.2 74.3 94.2C80.2 229.8 95.6 175.2 96 173.3z"
                  fill="#d03f3f"
                />
                <path
                  d="M215.2 200c-3.6 3-9.8 1-13.8-4.1-4.2-5.2-4.6-11.5-1.2-14.1 3.6-2.8 9.7-.7 13.9 4.4 4 5.2 4.6 11.4 1.1 13.8z"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <path
                  d="M428.4 201.3c0 49.2-74.4 94.2-74.4 94.2s-74.3-45-74.3-94.2a38 38 0 0 1 74.4-11.1 38 38 0 0 1 74.3 11.1z"
                  fill="#e24b4b"
                />
                <path
                  d="M292.2 173.3a37.7 37.7 0 0 0-12.4 28c0 49.2 74.3 94.2 74.3 94.2-77.8-65.7-62.4-120.3-61.9-122.2z"
                  fill="#d03f3f"
                />
                <path
                  d="M411.3 200c-3.6 3-9.8 1-13.8-4.1-4.2-5.2-4.6-11.5-1.2-14.1 3.6-2.8 9.7-.7 13.9 4.4 4 5.2 4.6 11.4 1.1 13.8z"
                  fill="#fff"
                />
                <path
                  d="M381.7 374.1c-30.2 35.9-75.3 64.4-125.7 64.4s-95.4-28.5-125.8-64.2a17.6 17.6 0 0 1 16.5-28.7 627.7 627.7 0 0 0 218.7-.1c16.2-2.7 27 16.1 16.3 28.6z"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <path
                  d="M256 438.5c25.7 0 50-7.5 71.7-19.5-9-33.7-40.7-43.3-62.6-31.7-29.7 15.8-62.8-4.7-75.6 34.3 20.3 10.4 42.8 17 66.5 17z"
                  fill="#e24b4b"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                className="sqd0Rating-5"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <g fill="#ffd93b">
                  <circle cx="256" cy="256" r="256" />
                  <path d="M512 256A256 256 0 0 1 56.8 416.7a256 256 0 0 0 360-360c58 47 95.2 118.8 95.2 199.3z" />
                </g>
                <path
                  d="M512 99.4v165.1c0 11-8.9 19.9-19.7 19.9h-187c-13 0-23.5-10.5-23.5-23.5v-21.3c0-12.9-8.9-24.8-21.6-26.7-16.2-2.5-30 10-30 25.5V261c0 13-10.5 23.5-23.5 23.5h-187A19.7 19.7 0 0 1 0 264.7V99.4c0-10.9 8.8-19.7 19.7-19.7h472.6c10.8 0 19.7 8.7 19.7 19.7z"
                  fill="#e9eff4"
                />
                <path
                  d="M204.6 138v88.2a23 23 0 0 1-23 23H58.2a23 23 0 0 1-23-23v-88.3a23 23 0 0 1 23-23h123.4a23 23 0 0 1 23 23z"
                  fill="#45cbea"
                />
                <path
                  d="M476.9 138v88.2a23 23 0 0 1-23 23H330.3a23 23 0 0 1-23-23v-88.3a23 23 0 0 1 23-23h123.4a23 23 0 0 1 23 23z"
                  fill="#e84d88"
                />
                <g fill="#38c0dc">
                  <path d="M95.2 114.9l-60 60v15.2l75.2-75.2zM123.3 114.9L35.1 203v23.2c0 1.8.3 3.7.7 5.4l116.8-116.7h-29.3z" />
                </g>
                <g fill="#d23f77">
                  <path d="M373.3 114.9l-66 66V196l81.3-81.2zM401.5 114.9l-94.1 94v17.3c0 3.5.8 6.8 2.2 9.8l121.1-121.1h-29.2z" />
                </g>
                <path
                  d="M329.5 395.2c0 44.7-33 81-73.4 81-40.7 0-73.5-36.3-73.5-81s32.8-81 73.5-81c40.5 0 73.4 36.3 73.4 81z"
                  fill="#3e4347"
                />
                <path
                  d="M256 476.2a70 70 0 0 0 53.3-25.5 34.6 34.6 0 0 0-58-25 34.4 34.4 0 0 0-47.8 26 69.9 69.9 0 0 0 52.6 24.5z"
                  fill="#e24b4b"
                />
                <path
                  d="M290.3 434.8c-1 3.4-5.8 5.2-11 3.9s-8.4-5.1-7.4-8.7c.8-3.3 5.7-5 10.7-3.8 5.1 1.4 8.5 5.3 7.7 8.6z"
                  fill="#fff"
                  opacity=".2"
                />
              </svg>
              <svg
                className="sqd0Rating-6"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                viewBox="0 0 512 512"
              >
                <path
                  d="M159.094 278.646h-1.042l-33.521-51.188-40.938-60.437h-31.75v176.395h35.062V232.312h1.521l29.104 44.542 44.688 66.562h31.938V167.021h-35.062v111.625zm47.375 75.52h25.834l64.791-196.332h-26.125l-64.5 196.332zm192.25-187.145h-35.833l-61.979 176.395h37.375l11.521-36.375h61.459l10.749 36.375h38.146l-61.438-176.395zm-39.438 110.604 7.146-23.292 13.604-45.832h1l13.854 46.604 6.896 22.521-42.5-.001z"
                  fill="#ff312e"
                  class="fill-1d1d1b"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <span>{ratingTextMap[sqd0]}</span>
      </div>

      {/* PREVIOUS & NEXT BUTTON */}
      <div className="page-content">
        <Stack
          direction="row"
          justifyContent="space-between"
          sx={{ marginTop: "15px" }}
        >
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              setStep(5);
            }}
            className="bottom-button"
          >
            Previous
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => setStep(7)}
            className="bottom-button"
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
#sqd0Rating-1:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}
#sqd0Rating-2:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  transform: translateY(-200px);
}
#sqd0Rating-3:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  transform: translateY(-300px);
}
#sqd0Rating-4:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  transform: translateY(-400px);
}
#sqd0Rating-5:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  transform: translateY(-500px);
}
#sqd0Rating-6:checked ~ .emoji-wrapper > .emoji {
  transform: translateY(-600px);
}
```

if you want to check the output here it is:
https://galmic.github.io/survey/

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippets directly in your question here and use the formatting tool to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your code much more readable and embed the SVG as a file rather than directly in HTML?
You could for example make it a React component. You're already doing this with your PNG files.

```
import SQD0 from "/path/to/sqd.svg";
<img src={SQD0} alt="SQD" />
```

It also has the benefit that you can use CSS directly on the component without having to copy and paste like your current CSS implementation.

Or use classic HTML:

```
<img src="/path/to/sqd.svg" alt="SQD" />
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but if you want to avoid copy paste in your CSS, you can use a for loop in SCSS:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  #sqd0Rating-#{$i} {
    transform: translateY(-100 * $i + px;)
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried something like this, I created 10 svg for each SQD, I am thinking if there is a way to use only 1 svg. let me elaborate.
When onChange is triggered in SQD0 the svg will change. but when I also when onChange in SQD1 or SQD2 etc. (which is not yet created) the SQD0 also changes. I know that it is because they have the same className, 
what approach can I make to make this happen in 1 svg only or it is not possible in my situation?